# Why is this query failing to compile?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What's wrong with this code?

```
Dim mycon As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlstring, game, ram, vga, scr, download, gametype, size As String
    game = TextBox1.Text
    download = TextBox2.Text
    scr = TextBox3.Text
    vga = TextBox4.Text
    ram = TextBox5.Text
    size = TextBox6.Text
    gametype = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString
    mycon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("../games.mdb"))
    mycon.Open()
    sqlstring = "INSERT INTO [Games] ( Name , url , image , Vga , Ram , Size , Type ) VALUES ('" + game + "' , '" + download + "' , '" + scr + "' , '" + vga + "' , '" + ram + "' , '" + size + "' , '" + gametype + "')"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlstring, mycon)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    mycon.Close()
```

When I run it, I get:

```
error in 
Line 21:         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

games schema 
id|Name|url|image|Vga|Ram|Size|Type

Stack Trace:

```
[OleDbException (0x80040e14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) +1090740
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) +247
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) +189
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) +58
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +162
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +107
   admin_editgames.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\New folder (4)\WebSite1\admin\editgames.aspx.vb:23
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553594
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: Use `Sqlparameter` class with sql data type for your query. Google it, help yourself.

Comment: Whenever you encounter an error, please post the exception message, and when applicable, the stacktrace.

Comment: Also, without knowing the schema for Games, it's hard to diagnose SQL insert issues.

Comment: ok i will add the stacktrace

Comment: In this case the stacktrace is probably less important than the actual exception message and exception type.

Comment: Regarding the schema the data types for each field is necessary. If one of those fields is numeric and one of those text boxes is passing along non-digits that is a problem.

Comment: Also, have you printed out the command text after you've built it?

Comment: id autonumber |and all next  are text

Comment: Did you print out the results of the concatenated query after it was built?

Comment: What is the value of sqlstring after you have assigned it?  But your query is open to sql injection attacks.  You should use parameters instead, plus it's easier and you don't have to worry about escaping characters like the apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Do any of your TextBox inputs have apostrophes ("'") in their input values? If so you'll need to escape them with another apostrophe:

```
game = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "'", "''")
' repeated for all variables
```

When you read about SQL injection attacks this sort of code is how they happen.

Comment: still the same problem errorSyntax error in INSERT INTO statement.